# When declaring static variable for conformance to AdditiveArithmetic, cannot call instance member from same type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I know this sounds crazy for a 10-year-old, but because S4TF doesn't work for me, I'm building my own neural network library in Swift. (I haven't gotten that far.) I'm creating a structure that conforms to `AdditiveArithmetic`. It also uses Philip Turner's [`Differentiable`](https://github.com/philipturner/differentiation), but that's unimportant.

Anyway, when defining the `zero` variable, I call another variable `dimen`, defined in the same structure. This raises an error: `instance member 'dimen' cannot be used on type 'Electron<T>'`

> note: the structure I am creating is going to be used to create a multi-dimensional array for neural networks.

Total code (stripped down to remove unimportant bits):

```
public struct Electron<T> where T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, T: AdditiveArithmetic {
    var energy: [[Int]: T] = [:]
    var dimen: [Int]
    public init(_ dim: [Int], with: ElectronInitializer) {
        self.dimen = dim
        self.energy = [:]
        var curlay = [Int](repeating: 0, count: dimen.count)
        curlay[curlay.count-1] = -1
        while true {
            var max: Int = -1
            for x in 0..<curlay.count {
                if curlay[curlay.count-1-x] == dimen[curlay.count-1-x]-1 {
                    max = curlay.count-1-x
                }
                else {break}
            }
            if max == 0 {break}
            else if max != -1 {
                for n in max..<curlay.count {
                    curlay[n] = -1
                }
                curlay[max-1] += 1
            }
            curlay[curlay.count-1] += 1
            print(curlay)
            energy[curlay] = { () -> T in
                switch with {
                    case ElectronInitializer.repeating(let value):
                    return value as! T
                    case ElectronInitializer.random(let minimum, let maximum):
                    return Double.random(in: minimum..<maximum) as! T
                }
            }()
        }
    }
    subscript(_ coordinate: Int...) -> T {
        var convertList: [Int] = []
        for conversion in coordinate {
            convertList.append(conversion)
        }
        return self.energy[convertList]!
    }
    public mutating func setQuantum(_ replace: T, at: [Int]) {
        self.energy[at]! = replace
    }
}
extension Electron: AdditiveArithmetic {
    public static func - (lhs: Electron<T>, rhs: Electron<T>) -> Electron<T> where T: AdditiveArithmetic, T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
        var output: Electron<T> = lhs
        for value in lhs.energy {
            output.energy[value.key] = output.energy[value.key]!-rhs.energy[value.key]!
        }
        return output
    }

    public static var zero: Electron<T> {
        return Electron.init(dimen, with: ElectronInitializer.repeating(0.0))
    }

    static prefix func + (x: Electron) -> Electron {
        return x
    }
    public static func + (lhs: Electron<T>, rhs: Electron<T>) -> Electron<T> where T: AdditiveArithmetic, T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
        var output: Electron<T> = lhs
        for value in lhs.energy {
            output.energy[value.key] = output.energy[value.key]!+rhs.energy[value.key]!
        }
        return output
    }
}
public enum ElectronInitializer {
    case random(Double, Double)
    case repeating(Double)
}
```

Error:

> NeuralNetwork.xcodeproj:59:30: error: instance member 'dimen' cannot be used on type 'Electron'
> return Electron.init(dimen, with: ElectronInitializer.repeating(0.0))

I don't know what's happening, but thanks in advance. I'm new to Stack Overflow, so sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: Because `zero` is a `static` function of the `struct`, it cannot access instance properties such as `dimen` because they aren't defined.  Can you pass `[]` instead of `dimen` in `zero`?

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for your answer! It helped me, but the problem is that my array is of varying size, `zero` will be variable depending on the `dimen` property. I understand this, though.

Comment: If `zero` requires dimensionality, then you're going to need to need one type for every one of those.  And `dimen` needs to be constant, not variable. (You are too young to be using such a bad name for things! Don't make up arbitrary abbreviations. Just use the entire word. Short naming is a thing that old people did for reasons that no longer apply.) See the SIMD types for inspiration.

Comment: One possibility is to define an `Electron` as a protocol and rename your existing `Electron` and make it conform to `Electron` and another `ZeroElectron` that also conforms to `Electron` and which ignores `dimen` and just returns 0 wherever appropriate.   That will mean writing even more generic code.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to add an `isZero` instance property and use it wherever you need to return 0 values.  I’d add a `private init` to construct it, since it’s an implementation detail.   The associated conditional checks will slow computation down, but if performance is an issue there are often ways to replace conditionals with computation - that’s a topic too large for a comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `dimen` is an *instance* property, while `zero` is a *static* property.  In a `static` context, you don't have an instance from which to access `dimen`, and so the compiler gives you the error.  `static` properties and methods are a lot like global variables and free-functions with respect to accessing instance properties and methods.  You'd have to make an instance available somehow.  For a `static` function, you could pass it in, but for a `static` computed property, you'd either have to store an instance in a *stored* `static` property, which isn't allowed for generics, or you'd have to store it in a global variable, which isn't good either, and would be tricky to make work for all the possible `T`.

There are ways to do what you need though. They all involve implementing some special behavior for a zero `Electron` rather than relying on access to an instance property in your `static` `.zero` implementation. I made some off-the-cuff suggestions in comments, which would work; however, I think a more elegant solution is to solve the problem by creating a custom type for `energy`, which would require very few changes to your existing code.  Specifically you could make an `Energy` type nested in your `Electron` type:

```swift
    internal struct Energy: Equatable, Sequence {
        public typealias Value = T
        public typealias Key = [Int]
        public typealias Element = (key: Key, value: Value)
        public typealias Storage = [Key: Value]
        public typealias Iterator = Storage.Iterator
        public typealias Keys = Storage.Keys
        public typealias Values = Storage.Values

        private var storage = Storage()
        
        public var keys: Keys { storage.keys }
        public var values: Values { storage.values }
        public var count: Int { storage.count }

        public init() { }
        
        public subscript (key: Key) -> Value? {
            get { storage.isEmpty ? .zero : storage[key] }
            set { storage[key] = newValue }
        }

        public func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
            storage.makeIterator()
        }
    }
```

The idea here is that when `energy.storage` is empty, it returns 0 for any key, which allows you to use it as a `.zero` value.  I've made it `internal`, because `energy` defaults to `internal`, and so I've done a minimalist job of wrapping a `Dictionary`, mainly providing `subscript` operator, and making it conform to `Sequence`, which is all that is needed by code you provided.

The only changes needed in the rest of your code are to change the definition of `energy`

```swift
    var energy: Energy
```

Then to set it in your initializer, by-passing the bulk of your `init` when `dim` is empty.

```swift
    public init(_ dim: [Int], with: ElectronInitializer) {
        self.dimen = dim
        self.energy = Energy() // <- Initialize `energy`

        // Empty dim indicates a zero electron which doesn't need the 
        // rest of the initialization
        guard dim.count > 0 else { return }
        
        var curlay = [Int](repeating: 0, count: dimen.count)
        curlay[curlay.count-1] = -1
        while true {
            var max: Int = -1
            for x in 0..<curlay.count {
                if curlay[curlay.count-1-x] == dimen[curlay.count-1-x]-1 {
                    max = curlay.count-1-x
                }
                else {break}
            }
            if max == 0 {break}
            else if max != -1 {
                for n in max..<curlay.count {
                    curlay[n] = -1
                }
                curlay[max-1] += 1
            }
            curlay[curlay.count-1] += 1
            print(curlay)
            energy[curlay] = { () -> T in
                switch with {
                    case ElectronInitializer.repeating(let value):
                    return value as! T
                    case ElectronInitializer.random(let minimum, let maximum):
                    return Double.random(in: minimum..<maximum) as! T
                }
            }()
        }
    }
```

And then of course, to change how you create it in your `zero` property

```swift
    public static var zero: Electron<T> {
        return Electron.init([], with: ElectronInitializer.repeating(0.0))
    }
```

`ElectronInitializer` isn't actually used in this case.  It's just a required parameter of your existing `init`.   This suggests an opportunity to refactor initialization, so you could have an `init()` that creates a zero `Electron` in addition to your existing `init(dim:with:)`

Comment: Thanks so much! The idea of an `internal struct Electron` helped me a lot.